# How to update data on server via AJAX when ng-model input value is changed

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I have one problem I cannot find a solution for. Any help is appreciated.

I'm fetching all the data from a server to a controller using `$http.get("/admin/getGraphData")`. When user edits `<input>` element, a data in controller is updated by Angular. When that occurs, I would want the data on the server (MySQL) to be updated instantly. Is there an easy way to achieve this? If I could do something like this:

```
$scope.onDayValueChange(month, year, day, newValue){
    $http.post("/admin/updateDayValue", {...})
}
```

But how to intercept Controllers data change and how to know exact index of object being changed or something like this? Thanks a lot!

Data model is fairly simple. Months (jan, feb, mar...) containing some value for each of a day in a month:

```
{month: 1, year: 2013, data:[{day:1, val:11}, {day:2, val:14}, ..., {day:31, val:80}]}
{month: 2, year: 2013, data:[{day:1, val:22}, {day:2, val:124}, ..., {day:30, val:2}]}
...
```

In HTML it looks something like this:

[image]

The code:

```
<div ng-app="graph" ng-controller="GraphCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li class="monthItem" ng-repeat="monthItem in months">
            <span>
                {{monthNames[monthItem.month-1]}} 
                ({{monthItem.month}}. 
                {{monthItem.year}}.)</span>

            <ul class="monthDays">
                <li ng-repeat="dayItem in monthItem.data">
                    <label>{{dayItem.day}}.
                    <input type="number" 
                        ng-model="dayItem.val"
                        value="{{dayItem.val}}"
                        min="0" required>
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('graph');
    app.controller('GraphCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    getData(); // load all data to the model

    function getData(){
        $http.get("/admin/getGraphData").success(function(data){
            $scope.months = data;
        })
    };

    $scope.monthNames = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
});
</script>
```

Comment: There is `ng-change` - fires when an `input` is changed. That's a lot of database writes tho, you may want to only write when the input is changed on `blur`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngBlur is a good option. Do your POST (PUT probably is more appropriate here) upon leaving the input field.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

Comment: The solution works! Thanks a lot! About PUT... How do you mean? I don't see any difference as I'm reading the data on server like this: `$data = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Comment: It doesnt make much of a difference on the server, but using PUT is the appropriate verb to use in a Restful sense.